# Delete item in the list view using Context Menu

Tags: java, android, listview, contextmenu

I want to use the context menu to delete an entry from the list view. 
This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Log.d("", "logger enter onContextItemSelected");
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        int i = (int) info.id;

        String list_record = separated.get(info.position);

        Utils.removeLabels(this, list_record);
        Log.d("", "labels>>> position: " + info.position);

        separated.remove(info.position);
        Log.d("", "labels>>> separated=" + separated);
        clAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here, info.position extracts the correct list_record but when I use the same thing in info.position, the item just below the selected item gets deleted. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//This is just an hack

int id = info.position == 0 ? 0 : info.position -1;
clAdapter.remove(clAdapter.getItem(id));
```

Comment: Try out "clAdapter.remove(clAdapter.getItem(0))" and see which one gets deleted ?

Comment: The one  that I selected for eg. i selected item at position 1 and it got removed

Comment: which is quite bizarre.

Comment: I guess the position value starts from Index 1 to n but the getItem Index starts from 0 to n. but I really dont know why.
Try this:

clAdapter.remove(clAdapter.getItem(info.position -1));

Comment: Yes i thought on the same lines and tried this before. But the index is from 0 to n-1 only. When you try deleting the first column in this case it throws the IndexOutOfBounds Exception (index being -1)

Comment: The updated code should work fine. but you need to check why there and indexing problem.